# React Native forms interlacing of data and formatting

Tags: react-native, forms, django-rest-framework

I probably need to explain a bit, its not a code answer i'm looking for. So say we have been using Django and crispy forms in Django and its been easy , not messy and semi elegant . What this means is we just retrive data from tables and have some forms defined and say use bootstarp and when we pass in data it does the formatting nicely for us. Grnated some amout of work involved in terms of placment of boxes but its not a lot of interlacing data and html, javascript etc

Now we are trying to move to django rest and React Native. We are react newbie ...somewhat. What ive noticed is there seems to be a lot of interlacing . Maybe I am doing it wrong, I'm trying to use formix and Django REST.

eems like we have to mix data and forms formatting together etc. Seems a little messy, am i missing something

1. IS formix the right way to go, what other popular forms should i look up
2. IS mixing all the react comoponents and formatting a common way. even though ive seprated it out into functions that churn the stuff out its still interlacing a lot of stuff like react components, formating and data together to build even a single form

is there a better cleaner way

Comment: It's understandable that forms are a pain in React. Did you tried  Formik - https://formik.org/ and Yup ?

Comment: Yes i have and its messy to say the least. is there no way of abstracting this in the same manner as django forms

Comment: The declarative programming nature of React makes form implementation become boring. Formik + Yup make a little better.